# Is there a method to send a log from Android-Studio to NodeJS/VisualStudioCode-Console?

Tags: java, android, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am developing an Android application. The backends runs with nodejs.

I want to send a log-message to the console, triggered if a boolean value in my Android Code is false.

Is there a method to send a log from Android-Studio to NodeJS/VisualStudioCode-Console?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean just an HTTP request?

Comment: Yes. I want to see on my Powershell/the console a short log-message, if my boolean value in the Android-Studio-Code turned false.

Comment: You need to send a message to your backend. Using HTTP, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! :)